# How to run TestCase in separate TestSuite WITH same context

Tags: soapui

In my SoapUI project, I have two test suites - CommonUtils and TestProper. I want to call the test case CommonUtils->UtilA from within TestProper->TestA, but I need my context shared between these two test cases. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Rhw.jpg

First, I tried adding a "Run TestCase" test steup to TestA. But, although I could transfer test case properties to UtilA, the "Run TestCase" did not allow me to transfer my context to UtilA.

Then, I tried to accomplish this by adding the following Groovy script to TestA:

```
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
def testCase = project.getTestSuiteByName('CommonUtils').getTestCaseByName('UtilA')
def contextMap = new StringToObjectMap(context)
testCase.run(contextMap, false)
```

Although this script allowed me to transfer *a copy* of my context into UtilA, UtilA was still unable to write to my context.

Now, I don't know how to accomplish this. How do I execute UtilA from within TestA, sharing variables between them?

Comment: There’s not much to go on here, but it sounds like utils contains a bucket of test cases you can then run from other test suites.  Do you run the CommonUtils suite as a suite in its own right? Can you clarify what sort of things are in utils?

Comment: I don’t follow why you would want to call a test case from another suite.  Not unless utils is really some common ‘functions’ you want to share.  If this is the case, Then maybe a test case isn’t what utils should be.  In my own suites, I call common scripts, helpers etc.  But I’ve written these as groovy classes stored in the SoapUi scripts folder.  That way I can call these helper scripts from any test in any suite.  If I need to fix a script, I just change it and any tests that use benefit from the change.

Comment: @ChrisAdams : If you're using the free edition of SoapUI, then you cannot make use of Groovy Library. You may be able to work your way around that locally, but the files you are using, will have to be passed around for anyone else who wants to run your SoapUI project. By making the functionality a part of your project, everything becomes self contained. No need to pass extra files along. (Apart from JAR files and the other usual suspects...)

Comment: Hi Steen, I did not know you cannot use the Groovy Library in the free edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the variables you want to pass around as context variables, it should work.

I did this in ReadyAPI, but I would expect it to work the same in SoapUI.

I created two TestSuites. Both holding a single TestCase.

The target TestCase just holds a Properties teststep, where I try to set a variable, and then one Groovy Script teststep with the following code:

```
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").setPropertyValue("varname",context.variable)
```

In the other TestSuite/TestCase I've got a single Groovy Script teststep, with just these two lines of code:

```
context.variable = "String set in testsuite StartTestCaseInAnotherTestSuite 2"
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite Name").getTestCaseByName("TestCase Name").run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(context),false)
// Remember to adjust the names of TestSuite and TestCase to suit your needs.
```

Now when I run the latter, I set the context.variable to a value, and when the second testcase is run, that context variable is set in the Properties teststep.

Comment: Hi, purely for my benefit and learning, what do you gain from calling another a test case in one suite from another?

Comment: You may have something that you do over and over in each testcase. Either setting something up. Prepping. Verifying something in a database. Something. It would be useful to be able to make a "method/function" that is reusable, and then just call that. Then if at some time you need to make changes to that, you only need to change it in one place. Not in every single testcase that you use it.

Comment: Ah, I get that, I do those sort of common tasks in Groovy script.  Especially response vs db validation.  Just never thought of using a test case to model such actions.  Thanks Steen.